# How can I tighten my shower head holder so that it doesn't slip and let the shower head drop out

Tags: bathroom, shower

I'm struggling to fix a shower head holder that seems to have loosened so that it no longer reliably cradles the shower head when the shower is not in use. What tends to happen now is that the shower head drops out of the holder when the shower is turned off. It seems the sudden drop in pressure leads to the holder failing to support the weight of the shower head. I think it's a ratchet inside the holder (see image below), and when the shower is shut off instead of holding the shower head in place it slips all the way round (making a quick succession of clicks). I'd be really grateful for any advice on how to deal with this problem please. Have tried tightening the screw that holds the shower head together, but to no avail. Thanks! - Siôn

[image: Shower head and shower head holder fully assembled]

[image: Closeup of shower head holder fully assembled]

[image: Internal mechanism of disassembled shower head holder]

Comment: Great pictures!  They make questions like this much easier to answer.  Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the last picture, it really looks like there used to be two "fingers" that engaged the ratchet mechanism.  One seems to be broken, which would also account for it no longer having the strength to hold the head in place.

If you're like me, you set this to the angle you like and never adjust it after that.  I would put some adhesive in the round channel outside of the ratchet ring and screw the parts back together, set the desired angle, and allow it to dry.

If you wanted it to be adjustable, you could fill that same channel with a small amount of rubbery adhesive (like a silicone sealant or shower caulking - something that doesn't get hard when it dries) and let it dry before putting the two sides together.  You just want a little rubbery adhesive in the groove to provide friction when the two pieces are screwed together.

Once it is dry, you can set it to the correct angle and tighten the screw to keep it in place.  If you needed to adjust it later, you might have to loosen the screw, but at least it's adjustable.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Went with the fixed angle solution suggested above and it worked a charm. Much obliged!

Answer (score 2):

I know the enquiry was from last year but it might be helpful to someone. I was also looking for the inner plastic part of the mechanism. I couldn't find the specific part but I did find the whole holder I just unclipped the shower head holder and put the new one in. I found it on: https://www.bathroomspareparts.co.uk/bristan-design-utility-lever-wall-bracket-hsj101-54959-p.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try to reverse the sprocket so the remaining finger is pointing up where the broken one is pointing. It may work better or worse but try. It is short term solution but maybe it works. Look up manufacturer if possible to order replacement.